Ionic Angular Android App and MSAL Authentication
I am currently working on an Android App with Ionic and Angular.
For authentication I want to use entra id (former Azure AD). For that I use the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for Angular.
The Web version works just fine, but on mobile device I am not being redirected back to the App. So I thought why not configure a custom uri for that like "myapp://auth" to redirect me to the App. That also works fine but the "#code..." section is not in the Uri so MSAL can not authenticate me in the Frontend.
Can someone give me a hint / help me. I do not find any documentation or sth. So if you have one, please tell me :)
Thank you all!
I already described it in the previous section
